# How can the graph of an equivalence relation be conceptualized?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Consider a generic equivalence relation $R$ on a set $S$. By definition, if we partition $S$ using the relation $R$ into $\pi_S$, whose members are the congruence classes $c_1, c_2...$ then

$aRb \text{ iff a and b are members of the same congruence class in } \pi_S$.

But what is the domain and codomain of $R$? Is it $S \rightarrow S $ or $S^2 \rightarrow \text{{true,false}}$?

The reason I ask is to have an idea of the members of $graph(R)$. Does it only contain ordered pairs which are equivalent, i.e. $(a,b)$; or all elements of $S \times S$ followed by whether they are equivalent, i.e. $((a,b), true)$?

Moreover, what would the image of $s \in S$ under $R$ look like? If one suggests that $R(s)$ would return a set of all the equivalent members, then the former definition is fitting.

I suppose the source of confusion is that we rarely think of equivalence relations as 'mapping' from an input to an output, instead it tells us if two objects are similar in some way.

Comment: $Domain=Codomain=S$ and the image of $s\in S$ is the congruence class containing $s$.

Comment: If you found any of the answers here helpful, please upvote them. Also, click the checkmark next to the answer which you found the most helpful to accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to define a relation $R$ on a set $S$ is as a subset of $S \times S$. Using this definition, we can create a graph $G = (S, R)$ where $S$ is the vertex set and $R$ is the edge set. In other words, if $a, b \in S$ are vertices of the graph $G$, then $(a, b)$ is an edge of $G$ if and only if $(a, b) \in R$ (i.e. $aRb$).

Now for an equivalence relation, two vertices are equivalent if and only if they are in the same component. Equivalently, two vertices $a, b$ are equivalent if and only if there is a path from $a$ to $b$.

Comment: I don't think he meant "graph" in a graph-theoretic sense

Comment: @Shahab What other kind of graph would you use for a general relation on a general set S (which may or may not consist of numbers)?

Comment: Abstracting the equivalence relation to a simple graph is a fine way to help my understanding. Indeed; I had meant the graph as a subset of the Cartesian of domain and codomain, but thinking in terms of a planar graph is perhaps the best way to visualize the relation.

Comment: @jesterII Note that the graph of a general relation is not guaranteed to be [planar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph). I'm pretty sure that you are not using the word "planar" by its technical meaning.

Comment: Indeed, what I mean by planar is the visual representation $G=(V,E)$, not graph meaning a subset of domain and codomain $graph(R) \subset X \times X$

Comment: @jesterII A *planar graph* is a graph $G = (V, E)$ which can be embedded in a plane without any edges crossing. In general, a relation $R$ is *not* guaranteed to have a graph representation which is planar in this sense.

Answer (score 0):

The domain is $S\times S$ and codomain is {true, false}.  Said another way, you can just think of any relation as a subset of $S\times S$.

Comment: Consider the identity function $f:S\to S$. It is an equivalence relation.

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: Because it satisfies the definition.

Comment: What is the definition of an equivalence relation?

Comment: A subset $f$ of $S\times S$ such that $(x,x)\in f, (x,y)\in f\Rightarrow (y,x)\in f, (x,y),(y,z)\in f\Rightarrow (x,z)\in f$, $\forall x,y,z\in S$.

Comment: In what sense is the identity function $f:S\to S$ a subset of $S \times S$?

Comment: Any function $f:S\to S $ is a subset of $S\times S$ such that every element of $S$ is the first component of one and only one ordered pair in the subset.

Comment: So the graph of $\mathrm{id}_S$ is an equivalence relation.